# Centering certain div elements while keeping another element at the bottom

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I have three elements in a div which itself is in another div. I want the first two elements of the inner div to be centered in relation to the outermost div and stacked on top of each other, while the third element should be at the bottom in relation to the outermost div as well. This is a WordPress project, which I am new to, so I don't want to change any of the div or class structure, just style the existing classes. I would prefer Flexbox-only solutions.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <p class="e1"> Centered element 1 </p>
        <p class="e2"> Centered element 2 </p>
        <p> Bottom element </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
.outerDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 90px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.innerDiv {
    align-self: center;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.e1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.e2{
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.innerDiv {
  /*...*/
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.e1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.e2{
   margin: 10px 0;
   margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

**Edit:** Added width/height properties to `.innerDiv`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I've updated this to meet your new requirements:

```
        .outerDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.e1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}

.e2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
}

.e3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the closest solution thus far, but I get the first two elements inline with each other, instead of stacked on top of each other (I should have clarified, I'll edit that into my question). More importantly however, the vertical alignment leaves me with the first two elements at the top with the third in the center. I am looking for the first two centered vertically, with the third element at the bottom.